# How can I deploy a re-trained Sagemaker model to an endpoint?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

With an `sagemaker.estimator.Estimator`, I want to re-[deploy](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/training/estimators.html#sagemaker.estimator.EstimatorBase.deploy) a model after retraining (calling `fit` with new data).

When I call this

```
estimator.deploy(initial_instance_count=1, instance_type='ml.m5.xlarge')
```

I get an error

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) 
when calling the CreateEndpoint operation: 
Cannot create already existing endpoint "arn:aws:sagemaker:eu-east- 
1:1776401913911:endpoint/zyx".
```

Apparently I want to use functionality like [UpdateEndpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateEndpoint.html). How do I access that functionality from this API?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, under the hood the `model.deploy` creates a model, an endpoint configuration and an endpoint. When you call again the method from an already-deployed, trained estimator it will create an error because a similarly-configured endpoint is already deployed. What I encourage you to try:

- use the `update_endpoint=True` parameter. From the [SageMaker SDK doc](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html):
  *"Additionally, it is possible to deploy a different endpoint configuration, which links to your model, to an already existing
  SageMaker endpoint. This can be done by specifying the existing
  endpoint name for the `endpoint_name` parameter along with the
  `update_endpoint` parameter as True within your `deploy()` call."*
- Alternatively, if you want to create a separate model you can specify a new `model_name` in your `deploy`

Comment: This method of adding `update_endpoint=True` to the `.deploy()` call does not appear to work if deploying from a `ModelPackage` obj. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/model-registry-deploy.html

Comment: This is a very good answer. I have a question though, if I have real time inference requests and the update endpoint is set to true, knowing that I have a few dozen requests per second, how would sagemaker handle inference while re-deploying ? would it use the old model to make inferences while updating is still in progress? thanks!

Answer (score 5):

`update_endpoint` has been deprecated since AFAIK . To re-create the `UpdateEndpoint` functionality **from this API itself** and deploy a newly fit training job to an existing endpoint , we could do something like this (this example uses the `sagemaker sklearn` API):

```
from sagemaker.sklearn.estimator import SKLearn

sklearn_estimator = SKLearn(
    entry_point=model.py,
    instance_type=<instance_type>,
    framework_version=<framework_version>,
    role=<role>,
    dependencies=[
         <comma seperated names of files>
    ],
    hyperparameters={
         'key_1':value,
         'key_2':value,
         ...
    }
)

sklearn_estimator.fit()

sm_client = boto3.client('sagemaker')

# Create the model
sklearn_model = sklearn_estimator.create_model()

# Define an endpoint config and an endpoint
endpoint_config_name = 'endpoint-' + datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%m%s")
current_endpoint = endpoint_config_name

# From the Model : create the endpoint config and the endpoint
sklearn_model.deploy(
    initial_instance_count=<count>,
    instance_type=<instance_type>,
    endpoint_name=current_endpoint
)

# Update the existing endpoint if it exists or create a new one
try:
    sm_client.update_endpoint(
        EndpointName=DESIRED_ENDPOINT_NAME, # The Prod/Existing Endpoint Name
        EndpointConfigName=endpoint_config_name
    )
except Exception as e:
    try:
        sm_client.create_endpoint(
            EndpointName=DESIRED_ENDPOINT_NAME, # The Prod Endpoint name
            EndpointConfigName=endpoint_config_name
        )
    except Exception as e:
        logger.info(e)

sm_client.delete_endpoint(EndpointName=current_endpoint)
```