# How can I update my custom build model in sagemaker everytime I create new training job?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I build a custom model on sagemaker and deployed the endpoint by creating a model. Now I want to retrain it every week and also I have to update same endpoint.

I scheduled the training job with lambda function but It is creating new artifact location. This is not I want. I want to update same model.

Does anyone know How can we do that?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. Please refer to his thread - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64169189/how-can-i-deploy-a-re-trained-sagemaker-model-to-an-endpoint.

Comment: Were you able to accomplish this?

Comment: @iCHAIT Yup! I did it with a AWS Lambda function which schedules a retraining job with aws cloudwatch.